# I can't call a variable

Tags: php

I can't call a variable inside $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST'

I tried calling a variable inside $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST' but it didn't work

```
my url is: localhost/learning/admin/index.php?cat&edit=1

if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $catid = $_GET['edit'];

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST') {

         $catedit = $_POST['catedit'];

         echo $catedit;
         echo $catid;

    }
 }

<form action="index.php?cat&edit" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="catedit">
    <button type="submit">Edit Category</button>

</form>
```

$catedit is showing but $catid is not showing. please help

When I echo $catid before if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST') then it is showing 1, what I want is to show $catid inside if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST')

Comment: If you send your form with `POST`, there is usually no `GET` data. Show your html form to get more info.

Comment: `GET != POST` and you need a poth `use $_REQUEST`

Comment: `edit` has no value.

Comment: `there is usually no GET data` that depends on the url of your action attribute in form tag @Wiimm

Comment: @Danyal Sandeelo: I know. At the time I'm wrote it, the OP has not provided the HTML code. So it was only a guess for a possible error and I wrote `usually`.

Comment: @Wiimm sure... I checked https://wiimmfi.de pretty nice stuff! (y)

Answer (score 0):

`?cat&edit`

when you get the values from `$_GET`, there will be 2 values in the array

1) cat

2) edit

but both would be empty since `cat` and `edit`, both do not have any value assignd to them.

If your form value is like

```
 <form action="index.php?cat=cat_value&edit=edit_value" method="post">
```

You would see values.